# How to implement a shared variable for the entire django project?

Tags: python, django, nginx, multiprocessing

I am writing a django server for a card game. The game begins when 2 players press the play button. To do this, in views.py I have the variable "turn", in which the id of the player who wants to play is recorded.

As soon as 2 players appear in the "turn", an instance of the class with the game is created for them and is written into the dictionary, for example: games_now = {"id1": "object at 0x0000027C04086D68", "id2": "object at 0x0000027C04086D68"}.
Thus, 2 players use one class and manipulate common variables in it.

So far, I run django as "manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80" on the server 1 core and do not notice any problems. But in production I have to use apache or nginx.

What happens if I run a django-project on nginx on a multi-core VPS?

Will all players then have access to the "turn" and "games_now" variables?

How can I implement the functionality of the game on a multi-core processor to avoid conflicts?

The game is implemented in the bot on vk.com
I receive requests from vk.com in the form {"from_id": from_id (int), "objects": {"message": message (text)}} and within 3 seconds I should return the answer 'ok' to the server. Therefore, everything else I do in the threads.

```
import threading
from json import loads

lock = threading.Lock()

turn = []
games_now = {}

def durak_main(request):

    req = loads(request.body)

    if 'type' in req:
        if 'object' in req:

            if 'message_new' in req['type']:

                threading.Thread(target=game_main, args=(req['object'] 
                                                         ['from_id'],),
                       kwargs={'message': req['object']['text']}).start()
                return HttpResponse('ok')

def game_main(from_id, message=None):

    if message == "play_online":

        with lock:
            if turn:
                enemy_id = turn[0]
                turn.remove(enemy_id)

                # Create game
                games_now[from_id] = OnlineGame(36, from_id, enemy_id)
                games_now[enemy_id] = games_now[from_id]

            else:
                turn.append(from_id)
```

In this code, I have no errors. But as the project grows, I will need to use multi-core VPS or some other solution. Please, help!

Comment: You could store state in the database. You could run some asynchronous worker (celery, channels). There are a lot of potential solutions to your problem

Comment: @IainShelvington And what is the best option you will advise? The load is potentially very large.

Comment: Well first of all you need to store the games in a shared datastore. Is there anything stopping you from just storing the game state in the database?

Comment: @lain 
The state that the player wants to play - of course, nothing prevents. Enough boolean type. But how to store the general class of the started game for two players in the database?

Comment: First you would have to create a `Game` model with fields for both users (foreign keys to the user model maybe) and when a user initiates a game you insert a new Game object into the database. On subsequent requests you can load the game that a user is assigned to

Comment: How to add a copy of the two-player game class to the database? What type of data should I use? As I understand it, we place all the games in the database so that we can create as many servers as possible?
And there is no solution for storing all states in RAM? After all, it will work faster?

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I am beginning to understand something!

Comment: No problem. Yes it would be faster to have everything in RAM but then you can only ever have 1 instance of your app or you have to implement some fairly complicated routing/sharding. It's probably easier to use the database for now until performance becomes an issue

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand much more. Finally, can you advise books in which I can learn how to implement some fairly complicated routing/sharding, if I need it in the future?